# collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: called only with UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader

Tags: ios, ios6

I have a collection view and I would like each section to have both a header and a footer. I'm using the default flow layout.

I have my own subclasses of `UICollectionReusableView` and I register each for both the header and the footer in the `viewDidLoad` method of my view controller.

I've implemented the method `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` but, for each section, it is only called with `kind` being `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`. Therefore my footer isn't even created.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 12):

It seems that I have to set the `footerReferenceSize` for the collection view layout. Weird that I didn't have to do that with the header.

Comment: I had the same experience (both header and footer) - it seems that if you don't set these, it doesn't attempt to load the header and footers. Honestly it feels like the API is missing a method like "- (BOOL)indexPath:hasSupplementalViewOfKind:" to let the developer explicitly determine which indexPaths have supplemental views.

Comment: How to increase the footer height?

Answer (score 9):

(Using Swift 3.1, Xcode 8.3.3)
**First**, register header's class or nib

```
collectionView.register(ShortVideoListHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
```

**Second**, set `headerReferenceSize`; alternatively, you can return `headerReferenceSize` in collectionView's delegate

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 156)
}
```

**Third**, write your own header class, such as,

```
class ShortVideoListHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(titleLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        titleLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 15, y: 64 + (frame.height - 64 - titleLabel.frame.height) / 2) // navigationBar's height is 64
    }
}
```

**Fourth**, return your header instance in collectionView's dataSource methods,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! ShortVideoListHeader
        header.titleLabel.text = title
        header.setNeedsLayout()
        return header

    default:
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}
```

By the way, [Apple's Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618037-collectionview) answers how to hide section header.

> This method must always return a valid view object. If you do not want a supplementary view in a particular case, your layout object should not create the attributes for that view. Alternatively, you can hide views by setting the 
>   hidden
>    property of the corresponding attributes to YES or set the 
>   alpha
>    property of the attributes to 0. To hide header and footer views in a flow layout, you can also set the width and height of those views to 0.

Comment: How to increase the height of the xib.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia set another reference size or return the new size in the corresponding delegate method, then reload the section or just reload the collection view.

Answer (score 3):

I found some code maybe can help you

```
- ( UICollectionReusableView * ) collectionView : ( UICollectionView * ) collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind : ( NSString * ) kind atIndexPath : ( NSIndexPath * ) indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView * reusableview = nil ;

    if ( kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader )
    {
        RecipeCollectionHeaderView * headerView = [ collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind : UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier : @ "HeaderView" forIndexPath : indexPath ] ;
        NSString * title = [ [ NSString alloc ] initWithFormat : @ "Recipe Group #%i" , indexPath.section + 1 ] ;
        headerView.title.text = title;
        UIImage * headerImage = [ UIImage imageNamed : @ "header_banner.png" ] ;
        headerView.backgroundImage.image = headerImage;

        reusableview = headerView;
    }
    if ( kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter )
    {
        UICollectionReusableView * footerview = [ collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind : UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier : @ "FooterView" forIndexPath : indexPath ] ;

        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was not the implementation of this method, as I stated in my answer. Also note that on iOS 7 the app crashes if you return nil.